# WPF Designer won't work when I add my Converter

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter

I have a simple value converter that I use. When I compile it works just fine but during the design WPF designer cannot find the resources. I don't know why.
Here is how I use it

```
xmlns:NumericConvertor="clr-namespace:NumericConverter"
xmlns:customName="NumericConvertor"
```

Then

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <NumericConvertor:PercentageConverter x:Key="percentageConverter"/>
</Grid.Resources>
```

And finally

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value , Converter={StaticResource percentageConverter} , Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Did you try to restart VS?

Comment: @mm8 Yes I did. It didn't help, when I use external assemblies it works. But when I try to use a namespace from my project it doesn't find it.

Comment: I use `xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:SO_app.Converters"` and then `<converter:DebugConverter x:Key="DebugConverter"/>`. Where Converters is a folder in my project. And DebugConverter is a plain converter. Don't know what `customName` is for?

Comment: @XAMlMAX with or without `customName`  doesn't matter, I usually use it to help designer resolve external assemblies.

Comment: I never had to use that to help resolve anything. However I know that sometimes if I create a converter adn include it in xaml without building project first I get some errors.

Comment: @XAMlMAX build and re-build didn't solve my problem here. It is indeed very weird problem.